# Reverse output of polyfit numpy

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I have used numpy's polyfit and obtained a very good fit (using a 7th order polynomial) for two arrays, x and y. My relationship is thus;

```
y(x) = p[0]* x^7 + p[1]*x^6 + p[2]*x^5 + p[3]*x^4 + p[4]*x^3 + p[5]*x^2 + p[6]*x^1 + p[7]
```

where p is the polynomial array output by polyfit.

Is there a way to reverse this method easily, so I have a solution in the form of,

```
x(y) = p[0]*y^n + p[1]*y^n-1 + .... + p[n]*y^0
```

Comment: Do you mean use the `y(x)` values of `p` to obtain a new set of `p` for `x(y)`, or use the same `x` and `y` data to find the new `p`?  If the latter, just swap `x` and `y` in `polyfit`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No there is no easy way in general.  Closed form-solutions for arbitrary polynomials [are not available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Example:_roots_of_polynomials) for polynomials of the seventh order.
2. Doing the fit in the reverse direction is possible, but only on monotonically varying regions of the original polynomial.  If the original polynomial has minima or maxima on the domain you are interested in, then even though y is a function of x, x cannot be a function of y because there is no 1-to-1 relation between them.
3. If you are (i) OK with redoing the fitting procedure, and (ii) OK with working piecewise on single monotonic regions of your fit at a time, then you could do something like this:

-

```
import numpy as np

# generate a random coefficient vector a
degree = 1
a = 2 * np.random.random(degree+1) - 1

# an assumed true polynomial y(x)
def y_of_x(x, coeff_vector):
    """
    Evaluate a polynomial with coeff_vector and degree len(coeff_vector)-1 using Horner's method.
    Coefficients are ordered by increasing degree, from the constant term at coeff_vector[0], 
        to the linear term at coeff_vector[1], to the n-th degree term at coeff_vector[n]
    """
    coeff_rev = coeff_vector[::-1]
    b = 0
    for a in coeff_rev:
        b = b * x + a
    return b


# generate some data
my_x = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.01)
my_y = y_of_x(my_x, a)


# verify that polyfit in the "traditional" direction gives the correct result
#     [::-1] b/c polyfit returns coeffs in backwards order rel. to y_of_x()
p_test = np.polyfit(my_x, my_y, deg=degree)[::-1]

print p_test, a

# fit the data using polyfit but with y as the independent var, x as the dependent var
p = np.polyfit(my_y, my_x, deg=degree)[::-1]

# define x as a function of y
def x_of_y(yy, a): 
    return y_of_x(yy, a)  


# compare results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.plot(my_x, my_y, '-b', x_of_y(my_y, p), my_y, '-r')
```

**Note: this code does not check for monotonicity but simply assumes it.**

By playing around with the value of `degree`, you should see that see the code only works well for all random values of `a` when `degree=1`.  It occasionally does OK for other degrees, but not when there are lots of minima / maxima.  It never does perfectly for `degree > 1` because approximating parabolas with square-root functions doesn't always work, etc.